# How to convert a project based on a master detail controller template to a simple model view controller template?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, ios5, master-detail

I started to create a project from the master detail template and realize that my main controller should be a simple mvc. Is there any simple method to do the conversion beside recreate a project from scratch with a mvc template? What should be edited then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templates just set up your appDelegate with the proper elements.  You could edit your appDelegate quickly, but unless you have a really compelling reason to edit the existing project it would likely be faster to just recreate the project.

With the master-detail template the appDelegate will have these properties (and code in the .m implementing them):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

The standard template will have these (plus the implementation code):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
```

The implementation file of the appDelegate will also be slightly different due to the NavigationController and SplitViewController in the master-detail.  You can just change these files around and update your xib files, but again, it's probably just as fast to start a new project.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. There were a bit more modification than what you suggested though. As i am in ios5 i had to: 1. edit the storyboard and remove the previous controller 2. create a new view controller in the storyboard 3. add a new uiviewcontroller subclass 4. as you mentioned edit the AppDelegate class. I wanted to proceed this way to keep track of my change in git.